# Comparing a element attribute with another element attribute using XQuery

Tags: xml, xquery

```
for $skill in $allskill
return <skill name = "{data($skill)}">{(for $i in 1 to 5
return (<count level = "{data($i)}" n = "{count($resumeSkills[@what = "SQL" and @level = "5"])}"></count> ))} </skill>
```

The snippet of code above works just fine how the code below does not.

```
for $skill in $allskill
return <skill name = "{data($skill)}">{(for $i in 1 to 5
    return (<count level = "{data($i)}" n = "{count($resumeSkills[@what = "{data($skill)}" and @level = "{data($i)}"])}"></count> ))} </skill>
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks .

Answer (score 1):

Remove the inner braces and quotes so that the corresponding part become :

```
n = "{count($resumeSkills[@what=$skill and @level=$i])}"
```

Notice that in your first XQuery, the quotes acts as delimiter for literal string, while in the second you don't use literal string anymore but using variables so no need for quotes here.